# profile in eclipse/jetty

Tags: java, jetty, profile

I have installed runjettyrun in Eclipse, now I can run/profile with jetty; but in the profiler config tab, there's no jetty selection. How can I add jetty to profile selections; or are there some other ways that can meet my need to profile a jetty hosted WS? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I rarely bother with eclipse plugins in this situation, opting instead to write a small main method that wires it up and runs it, or write a unit test that can be paused to examine state or debug.  There are a lot of examples in the jetty source of embedded usage in test cases.

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jetty/org.eclipse.jetty.project.git/tree/example-jetty-embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded

Those examples could help get you going if you choose to look into this option.